# Which one is correct? A Problem with making nouns out of sentences

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nouns

I'm trying to make a noun out of this sentence: **A remover of temporary files**.
Which of the following is correct and why, please?

1. A temporary file remover.
2. A temporary files remover.

Comment: Neither of your suggestions would usually be called a "noun", and your original text wouldn't usually be called a "sentence". They are all "noun phrases".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, it does. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I've downvoted your question because it's a duplicate. (You already admitted it yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, a noun used as an adjective is used in the singular:

A temporary *file* remover.